NSubstitute throws RedundantArgumentMatcherException fails subsituted interface is global but not local
Can anyone help me to understand why a local instance of the substitute runs fine, but not then its a field? It happens on an Azure pipeline where the agent runs on a windows machine. However I cannot reproduce it locally.
Examples below:
public class RiskTests
{
    private readonly IRankGenerator rankGenerator = Substitute.For<IRankGenerator>();
    private const string OriginalRisk = "Danger danger";
    private const string OriginalRank = "Rank 1";
    private Risk sut;

    public RiskTests()
    {
        sut = Risk.Create(CreateTest(), OriginalRisk, OriginalRank);
        rankGenerator().GenerateRank().ReturnsForAnyArgs(_ => "000001");
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Should_Add_Mitigation()
    {
        sut.AddMitigation("Do this to be safe", rankGenerator);
        
        sut.Mitigations.ShouldNotBeEmpty();
        sut.Mitigations.Count.ShouldBe(1);
        
        sut.AddMitigation("And this is important", rankGenerator);
        sut.Mitigations.Count.ShouldBe(2);
    }
}

Passed test example:
public class RiskTests
{
    private readonly IRankGenerator rankGenerator = Substitute.For<IRankGenerator>();
    private const string OriginalRisk = "Danger danger";
    private const string OriginalRank = "Rank 1";
    private Risk sut;

    public RiskTests()
    {
        sut = Risk.Create(CreateTest(), OriginalRisk, OriginalRank);
        rankGenerator().GenerateRank().ReturnsForAnyArgs(_ => "000001");
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Should_Add_Mitigation()
    {
        var localRankGenerator = rankGenerator;
        sut.AddMitigation("Do this to be safe", localRankGenerator);
        
        sut.Mitigations.ShouldNotBeEmpty();
        sut.Mitigations.Count.ShouldBe(1);
        
        sut.AddMitigation("And this is important", localRankGenerator);
        sut.Mitigations.Count.ShouldBe(2);
    }
}

